# Rename page title shown in GA via Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to replace the original page title in GA with custom variable via Goggle Tag manger. I have set to overwrite the field with the value but it turns out showing undefined in GA.

May I know if there's any solution for that?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the value of the variable {{PagePath - Restructure}} in GTM preview? Check if that is undefined.

Comment: Thanks @MichelePisani, the variable of {{PagePath - Restructure}} is not undefined as shown. But not sure why it showed undefined in GA. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is not undefined also when pageview is sent?

Comment: When the page loaded in preview mode, the variable is shown as above. how can I check if the variable is undefined when pageview is sent? Are you referring to the page title show in GA? Is there any constrain that the page title cannot be overwritten? Sorry if these are stupid questions as I am new to Google Tag Manager. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Click on pageview on the right in GTM preview, and check the value of the variable in that state

Comment: Updated the screen cap of the GTM preview. The variable have value. Thanks

Comment: Pageview is sent on productPage event? What events in position 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Check in 'Container Loaded (gtm.js)' status.

Comment: Oh Yes! You are right. It return undefined in 'container loaded'. What can I do in this case? Thanks for your patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments showed that `title` value return undefined in 'container loaded' event, so a solution could be use 'productPage' event as trigger instead of 'all pages', in any case a state where the title has a value other than undefined (pageview may be sent with a slight delay compared to container load (gtm.js)).

Comment: Appreciated for your help. It works! Thanks again for your patient.